# Iter.remove() Method Error

Tags: java, iterator

I am having some trouble implementing the `iterator.remove()` method correctly. I am trying to use the method to remove certain strings from an `ArrayList` of strings, but every time I try using an iterator (and the `iterator.remove()` method), I get an error titled "Check For Comodification". I am posting my code below for reference. Appreciate the help!

```
        Iterator<String> iter= myWords.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){  
            String current= iter.next();
            for(int i=0;i<current.length();i++){
                if(current.charAt(i)==mostFrequentChar){
                    iter.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks okay. What error do you get exactly, and at which line?

Comment: Is it possible that the iterator method is returning a _singletonish_ object that could be being modified elsewhere at the same time?

Comment: @user114241 No. Each call to `iterator` returns a new iterator, per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

"Check For Comodification" usually means that something is already modifying the **Collection** at the same time while iterating over it. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) out.